# How to place all references in the tex file (not in a bib file)

Tags: bibliographies

I'm wondering how to place all references in the main tex file (not in a bib file)

thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management (see section 1). There are also other solutions, but you have to be more precise with what you want.

Comment: Yes, copy and replace the lines calling Bibtex by the contents of the .bbl file is the best solution for me.